# how to create a small search engine

Tags: mysql, search

I'm aim to create a small in-app search engine(something like a google map address search bar).The requirement is quite simple.The item is consisted of many key-words,the user types in a key-word,it gives out corresponding result,the user types in another key-word after that,it continues to filter the result.

The first thing come to my mind is to use mysql,create a key-words table to store every key-wrods and like it to the item table,and when user type in a key-word,it searched through every record in key-words table to give results.Am I thinking in the right way?Could u guys give me some helps?I'm a totally novice in mysql(only learn it in high school lesson).Is there any open-source platform for this?

Comment: It seems like you are taking a reasonable approach so far.
Which language/environment are you using? Are you trying to make a simple Web based application? Will the results table comprise hyperlink URL/text?

Comment: This is a similar question as asked before. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384276/how-do-i-create-a-search-engine-like-google

Comment: Use **Jquery** and **like** in mysql.

Comment: @Matthew Slyman I'm trying to use php+web service ,but not sure how to structure the database.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: If your don't need to store keyword frequency, then go with Marmik Bhatt's `LIKE` suggestion.*

If you have large amount of data and you want to do a keyword search only (i.e. you are not going to be searching for phrases or use concepts like "near"), then you can simply create a keyword table:

```
CREATE TABLE address
(
  id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  /* ... */
);

CREATE TABLE keyword
(
  word VARCHAR(255),
  address_id INT(10),
  frequency INT(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(word, article_id)
);
```

You then scan through the text that you are "indexing" and count each word that you find there.

If you want to do several keywords:

```
SELECT address.*, SUM(frequency) frequency_sum
FROM address
INNER JOIN keyword ON keyword.address_id = address.id
WHERE keyword.word IN ('keyword1', 'keyword2', /*...*/)
GROUP BY address.id;
```

Here i've done a frequency sum, which can be a dirty way to compare the usefulness of the result, when many are given.

Things to think about:

- Do you want to insert all keywords into the database, or only those, that have a frequency higher than a specific value? If you insert all your table may become huge, if you insert only higher frequency ones, then you will not find the only article that mentions a specific word, but does so only once.
- Do you want to insert all the available keywords for the specific article or only "top ones"? In this case the danger is that frequent words that add nothing to the meaning will begin pushing others out. Consider the word "However", it may be in your article many more times than "mysql", buy it is the latter that defines the article, not the former.
- Do you want to exclude words shorter then a specific length of characters?
- Do you want to exclude known "meaningless" words?

Comment: Hello Volodya I'm not trying to find an article,just to retrieve a item ,each item has many keywords,and when user type in a keyword,the engine filters some results,and the user type in another keyword ,it filters from the previous results,etc.

Comment: @TomTian Simply add each following keyword within `IN` operator's brackets.

Answer (score 1):

For search engine, I use 'LIKE' to search parameters...
The query would look like...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_keywords
INNER JOIN tbl_addresses ON tbl_addresses.id = tbl_keyword.address_id
WHERE tbl_keywords.keywords LIKE "% $keyword %";
```

$keyword is a variable retried from GET or POST request from the search bar.

You can also use JSON output of your search result so, using jquery you can provide fast search result output.

### Full Text Search

You can also use full text search for  searching for places and related keywords
see this link...[SQL Full Search Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can implement is that you can break down the user keyword based on spaces and it will fetch you out most relevant results.

For example, user types **Create search engine**

then explode it based on space.

Then query DB for each word.

A [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) *might* be more efficient, but you'd have to benchmark it to be sure, e.g.

```
SELECT * from fiberbox where field REGEXP 'Create|search|engine';
```

Use [jQuery Autocomplete](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) to make an auto-suggest search like Google does

Comment: When the user typed in the first keyword "create" the engine will give corresponding results,but how do I store those results for the second keyword "search"?and the third keyword etc.

Comment: Or is it like this:when user type in some keywords separated by space.the query will automatically filter items match the keywords at one time?instead of filter one by one?

Comment: @TomTian you misundertood it .... you dont have to store it anywhere .... with jquery-auto-complete ... when your key is pressed and the released ... the string typed so far, is sent to server and matching results are returned .....

Comment: see here is a good tutorial and a good demo on the same page

http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step#my-demo

Comment: And here is the link to the website who created it 

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thank you so much.I probably should go back to learn query language before I can figure them out.